# Clear up saved name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Hi, I have first project on React, and I wanna to clear up entry field after submit

```
                <PresetModalInputWrapper>
                    <PresetModalInput
                        placeholder={'Preset Name'}
                        value={presetName}
                        onChange={(event) => setPresetName(event.target.value)}
                    />
                    {doesContainError ? (
                        <PresetErrorMessage>{messagePresetWithSuchNameExists}</PresetErrorMessage>
                    ) : null}
                </PresetModalInputWrapper>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Are you just asking how to set a blank value to the `presetName` state value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a button that executes the `setPresetName` function, like this:

```html
<button onClick={() => setPresetName('')} />
```

or on a `handleSubmit` function

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // ... your submit logic here

    setPresetName('')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by calling `setPresetName('')` on the button click event